# Falha ao consumir Webservice da NF-e 4.0 SEFAZ Ceará (CE)

Tags: web-service, nfe

Depois de baixar os WSDLs da SEFAZ do Ceará e testar a conexão o com o serviço **NFeStatusServico4** obtive o erro:

`Falha na solicitação com resposta vazia.`

ou em inglês

`The request failed with an empty response`

A nova versão da NF-e pede que a conexão seja TLS 1.2 e, mesmo após a configuração, estes erros de comunicação estavam ocorrendo. O estranho é que, após baixar os WSDLs da SEFAZ de SP, o envio para SP com o mesmo código está funcionando.

Obs.: usei .NET para testes e comunicação com os webservices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao analisar o processamento e verificar o log de processamento da chamada, percebi os endereços dentro dos WSDLs da SEFAZ CE estão errados, para uma comunicação segura. Desta forma, para funcionar, tive que alterar a URL:

`http://nfeh.sefaz.ce.gov.br:80/nfe4/services/NFeStatusServico4`

para

`https://nfeh.sefaz.ce.gov.br/nfe4/services/NFeStatusServico4`

Conforme solicitação da SEFAZ, enviei e-mail para eles relatando o problema.

Comment: se possível feche a questão como resolvida marcando seu comentário/resposta como correto :)

Comment: O sistema diz que só posso fazer isso depois de 2 dias...